# Sphere sliding down infinite inelastic ladder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

I have come up across the following question about newtonian physics:

> A homogenous sphere of mass m and radius r is sliding down an infinite ladder with height and width of the step x, where x << r. The ladder is inelastic. What will be the maximum velocity of the sphere? I only know that the answer is not "infinity" but cannot understand why. Any thoughts?

Update: Forgot to mention: there is no friction. 
The source of this question is USSR national physics olympiad 1971.

Comment: Could you give the book or similar where you saw the problem?

Comment: This is not from a book. My father told me about this question. He came across it during USSR physics olympiad back in 1971

Comment: If there is no friction, then the ball is not rolling.

Comment: True! I have edited the question

Comment: "**Infinite ladder with height and width $x$**". Also how can a sphere roll down a ladder, anyways? Won't it fall through the gaps between the footbars?

Comment: I meant the height and width of the step. I will correct the question

Comment: If this is supposed to be a straightforward classical physics problem, the ball will reach an infinite speed.  No other answer is possible.  If you are supposed to take air resistance into account, the ball will have a maximum speed due to air resistance, but it seems that you are not given enough information to calculate it.  If we consider special relativity, the ball will have a maximum speed of $c$, but that has nothing to do with the height and width of the step.  I'm sorry, but something must be missing here, or not phrased well.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I don't think national olympiad question would be straightforward. And no, the answer is not infinity. I suspect that reason is because of inelasticity, which means that part of velocity is lost on every touch between sphere and a ladder.

Comment: I apologize for introducing any confusion with my edits. I didn't understand the question initially. I had temporarily changed the question, but now I've reverted it back to how it was originally posed